# my ajax is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting error in Ajax by using the method post and getting the total attendance between two dates of the selected person.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#submit").click(function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var fromdate = $("#fromDate").val();
                        var todate = $("#toDate").val();
                        var dep = $("#dep").val();
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" +"index.php/Ajaxcontroller/getAttendence",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {from: fromdate, to: todate,dep:dep},
                            cache:false,
                            success: function(result) {
                                $("#row2").html(result);

                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: did you include jquery link?

Comment: console.log out the result from error.

Comment: console.log(result) what's the error

Comment: And the *obvious* question would be... **what is the error?**

Comment: how to do that @MCMXCII

Comment: showing the alert "error" @David

Comment: update `error: function () {` to `error: function(obj, error, thrown) {` then add  `console.log(error);` above `alert("error");`

Comment: @Anu: You're getting that alert because that's what you wrote: `alert("error")`  Don't obscure useful error messages with useless ones.  Find the *actual error*.  Add an argument to the `error` callback and see what is passed to it.  Or even take a look at the network tab in your browser's debugging tools and see the actual response from the server.

Comment: updated as u said..but showing the same alert error..@MCMXCII

Comment: Okay, but what is it saying in the console?

Comment: XHR failed loading: in console@MCMXCII

Comment: @Anu: What if you also log the other parameters passed to the error callback?  What is the actual response from the server in the network debugging tools?  Basically, you have to find out *what the error is*.

Comment: I think it's URL concatenation error 
try

`url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Ajaxcontroller/getAttendence", `

Comment: i have used the url like this in others..@PrAtikLochawala

Comment: @David: how to how to pass parameters to error callback.

Comment: Update the `console.log(error);` you put in before to `console.log(obj, error, thrown);` and see what comes out in the console.

Comment: @Anu: Exactly as you were previously shown and as you previously indicated that *you already did*: `error: function(obj, error, thrown)`

Comment: **my function is like this and can u edit this code.** error: function(obj, error, thrown) {
                            console.log('error');
                            alert("error");
                        } @MCMXCII

Comment: No, note the difference between `console.log(error)` and `console.log('error')`

Comment: So, update the `console.log(error)` to `console.log(obj, error, thrown)` and see what comes out in the console.

Comment: i have update as u said like this ~error: function(obj, error, thrown) {
                            console.log(error);
                            alert("error");
                        }~ help me to change this code. @MCMXCII

Comment: Update `console.log(error)` to `console.log(obj, error, thrown)`

Comment: @MCMXCII:getting same error

Comment: And what responses are you getting from the other objects?

Comment: getting the alert error @MCMXCII

Comment: In your console.

Comment: {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, getResponseHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} "error" "Internal Server Error"
15:49:05.944 jquery.js:4 XHR failed loading:   getting like this @MCMXCII

Comment: So, your error is an "Internal Server Error". That would suggest that your AJAX is fine and the problem actually exists within the PHP function you are calling. Edit your question with the contents of the getAttendence function.

Comment: this is my controller

Answer (score 0):

```
**this is my controller..**

    public function getAttendence()
    {   
        if($this->input->post() && $this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            $credentials=array(
                'from' => $this->input->post('from'),
                'to' = $this->input->post('to'),
                'dep' => $this->input->post('dep')        
            );
            $this->load->model('Ajaxmodel');
            if($this->Ajaxmodel->selectAttendence($credentials)){
                $data['result']=$this->Ajaxmodel->selectAttendence($credentials);              
                echo json_encode($data);
            }            
        }   
        else{
             $this->load->view('Salarycontrol');
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Just for clarity, move `>selectAttendence($credentials);` up to the line before it e.g. `$data['result']=$this->Ajaxmodel->selectAttendence($credentials);`

Comment: So, to try and debug this, put `echo json_encode([]);exit();` on the first line of the method and confirm that AJAX request now works.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as
data: {'from': fromdate, 'to': todate, 'dep':dep}

If still getting error please elaborate the error exactly you are getting

Comment: That exactly mean the url you are requesting is not responding, please ensure requesting url is called or not by adding a error log in your controller like 
public function getAttendence() { 
     error_log('called'); then Check your error log file

Comment: i have given the url and added error log but getting the same error..please help me to solve this error

Comment: There is an error in your requesting url. Remove this <?php echo base_url(); ?>" +"index.php/Ajaxcontroller/getAttendence". And add absolute url eg. Url : 'index.php',
data: {'controller' : 'Ajaxcontroller', 'from': fromdate, 'to': todate, 'dep':dep}

Comment: showing this error in console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  @Vikash

Comment: Please align url such that it ll find controller successfully because i don't have idea about the code written in your index.php page